# Wrong timestamp in googlesheet

Tags: wordpress, google-sheets, plugins, timestamp, elementor

I have an issue with timestamps in google sheet. I use WordPress, Elementor and some plugins to send my data to google sheet.
The problems are that the timestamp, date or time have an extra ' sign at the beginning. I have this issue with several plugins which I used. For instant :

```
'2021-03-12 11:03 pm
```

However, when I copy that cell and paste it here for example, there is no ' sign at the middle. I just paste the copied cell:

```
2021-03-12 11:03 pm
```

Anyone knows what is wrong, is it with googles or WordPress and how to solve it?
thank you

Comment: I guess that in your situation, when the value is put from WordPress to Google Spreadsheet, the value of `valueInputOption` used for Sheets API might be `RAW`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption) I thought that this might be the reason of your current issue. But if I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: *"Anyone knows what is wrong, is it with googles or WordPress"* As mentioned by @Tanaike this is how WordPress behaves. Still. *"and how to solve it"*. Solve what? Not to be entered this way or do you want to further use the data (and if so how) and face problems with it? Please clarify.